# О письменности справа налево и слева направо

Tags: орфография, история, письменность

Обращалась к нескольким специалистам-филологам, историкам с вопросом, **почему одна часть человечества пишет слева направо, а другая - справа налево.** Прошерстила пару учебников по истории письма. Вразумительного ответа на свой вопрос так и не нашла. Отсылки к эзотерике меня не совсем устраивают. Возможно, это не совсем филологический вопрос. И все-таки хотелось бы услышать мнение заинтересованных.

Comment: Найдите Иллюстрированную всеобщую историю письмен Я.Б. Шницера. Там, стр. 84, 166  — вразумительный ответ по всем алфавитам.

Answer (score 3):

Очень интересный вопрос! 
Нашла кое-что здесь: http://foren.germany.ru/arch/wissen/f/3855720.html

В древние времена финикийцы писали справа налево, ассирийцы - слева направо, а египтяне, для которых письмо было неразрывно связано с живописью, иногда в одну, а иногда в другую сторону. Нередко даже помещали один и тот же текст на стеле или саркофаге дважды: слева от рисунка шёл текст слева направо, а по другую сторону рисунка √ зеркальное отражение того же текста. Китайцы на Тайване пишут как правило сверху вниз, причём столбцы идут справа налево. В КНР принято европейское направление. Таким образом видно, что нет «естественного» направления письма.
Евреи, перенявшие письмо у финикийцев, сохранили более древнее направление письма. Древние греки писали одну строку в одном направлении, а вторую навстречу: так называемый бустрофедон, или «пахота вола». Пахарь, дойдя до конца борозды, не возвращается к началу поля, а заворачивает вола и пашет следующую борозду в обратном направлении. Позднее греки стали писать слева направо, и от них это направление переняла вся Европа. Еврейским, арабским и сирийским письмом пишут до сих пор справа налево.

Потому никаких религиозных, мистических или биологических уршпрунгов тут нет. Просто в свое время при зарождении письменности по воле случая изобразили так..
(http://foren.germany.ru/arch/wissen/f/3855720.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Все это известная информация. Мне там, кстати, понравился комментарий, что большинству людей писать слева направо просто удобнее. Но арабы, например, пишут справа налево, а соотношение правшей и левшей у них, вероятно, то же, что и везде.

Comment: Наверное, и письменные знаки подстроились под тип письма. Хотя левши пишут совсем по-другому, и ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, вы не найдете прямого ответа на вопрос "почему?". Так сложилось. Где-то закрепился случайный выбор, где-то возможно сказались свойства пишущего инструмента и "бумаги", где-то переняли у других народов. Сакральной закономерности действительно нет - и вряд ли она возможна.

Могу только добавить, что соотношение левшей и правшей не столь одинаково у всех народов, как считалось ранее. Но это вряд ли могло как-то сказаться на выборе направления для той или иной письменности. Тем более непонятно, какую руку считать главной у высекающего наскальную надпись: держащую зубило или молоток.

Comment: Спасибо! Была одна надежда - на вас =))

Answer (score 1):

1. Считается, что наиболее древней формой направления записи был бустрофедон - то есть запись сначала справа-налево, потом слева-направо. Объяснение этому факту очень простое, потому что первые письмена буквально высекались на скалах/стелах - в общем это было некое не столько информация-надпись, сколько узор. Соответственно логично было каменотесу передвигать леса постепенно туда - потом назад. Именно этим и объясняется направление надписей у египтян, которое обнаруживает все признаки бустрофедона. Аналогично писали и древние тюрки, поскольку их надписи в основном делались на камнях.
2. Далее, я полагаю, когда письмо началось переноситься на более облегченные носители: папирус, кожа, бумага, береста и проч., когда появилась скоропись - бустрофедон исчез и в зависимости от начертания букв выжили 2 основные формы: слева-направо и справа-налево.
3. Видимо на направление мог влиять размер знаков. Например, если принятые знаки были крупными, то более удобным становился способ записи справа-налево: чтобы рисунок знака получился аккуратным, надо было видеть поле расположение будущего знака и разметить воображением пропорции заранее, а не заслонять её кистью руки, держащий инструмент для нанесения штрихов. Простой пример: дети пишущие крупными буквами, не замечали, что они плохо выдерживают размеры/линии ближе к концу строки? Именно по этой причине, что не могут оценить конец строки потому что он загораживается кистью. Ну и наоборот, если знаки были мелкие - то "побеждает" способ записи слева-направо.

**P.S.** Великий Леонардо был уверен, что удобнее писать справа-налево и так и писал!

Comment: Спасибо! Вы полагаете, нет никакой связи с право-/леворукостью? По крайней мере, Леонардо было удобно писать справа налево, потому что он сам был левшой :-))

Comment: Полагаю, что лево-праворукость совершенно не причем. Ну а Леонардо - он же гений :) к нему обычные правила неприменимы

Answer (score 0):

В основном арабы писали и пишут справа налево по той простой причине, чтобы тень от руки не попадала на папирус, пергамент и т.д. А лампу во время письма они ставили с левой стороны. Этот вопрос я не оспариваю. Это моё мнение.

Comment: Лампу можно поставить туда, где удобнее. Да и вопрос тени сомнительлен... Она все равно ведь куда-то падет, при любом положении руки.  
Все бы ничего, но арабская письменность (тем более - её первоосновы, финикийская и ханаанейская) возникла так давно, что ни о какой бумаге и речи не было. Куда вернее то, что так было удобнее, если держать молоток в правой руке, а зубило в левой.  
Впрочем, это всё уже обсуждалось выше.